# import image with Javascript to jsp

Tags: javascript

On my JSP I was using:

```
<img id="sharkgraphic" src="<c:url value="/images/fcs1.svg"></c:url>"/>
```

otherwise the browser could not find the svg file. Now I want to be able to set the src in javascript.

I tried using:

```
      var sharkurl = require("../images/fcs1.svg");
      $( "#sharkgraphic").attr("src",sharkurl);
```

How would I properly set the source of that img ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on deployment setup of your application. 
*c:url* without *context* attribute is resolved to {context of app}/{value}, e.g. if your app deployed to

```
http://localhost:8080/my-app
```

then

```
src='<c:url value="/images/fcs1.svg"/>'
```

be resolved to

```
src='/my-app/images/fcs1.svg'
```

in this case

```
$("#sharkgraphic").attr("src","/my-app/images/fcs1.svg");
```

should work fine